# Adding to a hashmap inside of a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is what I have:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Integer>> data =
            new HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();
```

But I am having trouble adding values to this, because the inner hashmap doesn't have a name (note: it isn't supposed to). I'm actually trying to add an array list to the first Integer in HashMap So I am trying something like:

```
data.put(var, data.get(array.get(x), y));
```

Which it very much doesn't like and I'm totally clueless as to how to do it.

Comment: what is the value of array.get(x) and y?

Comment: I'd suggest u to take a look on Guava libraries Mulitmap. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Answer (score 5):

Note that

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Integer>> data =
            new HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();
```

only creates the "outer" HashMap instance. After this statement you have an empty HashMap that takes Strings as keys and `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` as value.

You can add an instance of `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to `data` with this:

```
data.put("myKey", new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
```

After that you can add Integer values to the second HashMap:

```
data.get("myKey").put(123, 456); // use 123 as key and 456 as value
```

Get the values back:

```
data.get("myKey").get(123); // returns 456
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the inner hash map first:

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> innerData = data.get(var);
```

Then you can put your value into it:

```
innerData.put(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Integer>> data =
            new HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();
((Map)data.get( "keyname" )).get(1);
```

and subsequently:

```
   ((Map)data.get( "keyname" )).get( 1 ).put(2);
```

Comment: Note that the second has map uses integers

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
data.put( var, new HashMap(intKey, intVal));
```

where intKey and intVal are Integer type Key and Integer type value.